# css div floating

Tags: css, html

I have two `<div>` tags inside a container. one of them floating right and the other one floating left.
I'm trying to line them up but the problem is that the right one goes under the left one, and doesn't float at all.

http://tinkerbin.com/QuHxRQXO

Comment: many mistakes in your code check once.

Comment: hmmm...i don't know exactly what mistake you are talking about

Comment: `Font` is missing closing tag and `p` is in caps in someplaces and a special character. These errors doesnt mean anything to the code problem but you should check them. :)

Comment: can you post your desired result screenshot what exactly do you want ?

Comment: It's your problems pretty simple your container isn't big enough. http://jsfiddle.net/89ag7/

Comment: http://tinkerbin.com/QuHxRQXO

Comment: i'm trying to get the part that it's a the bottom to line up with the center and go right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/aeFx3/).

It's not being float at right because you are giving padding to your `div`'s which is making your `.rightside` div to come bottom. Instead of giving padding to `div`'s give padding to inside elements.

Instead of giving `px` to your `div`'s give percentages. It helps you to understand the pattern.

I removed padding from your div's and added padding to the inner elements just like below.

```
h4,p{padding:5px;}
```

Comment: check this @user1665569 This maybe what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
It  is working fine. I have checked except.

change
<font color= "#FFFFFF"><b>Site Contents</b>
 to
<font color= "#FFFFFF"><b>Site Contents</b></font>

<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
<html>
<head>
<title> new document </title>
<style type="text/css">
.subcontent{width:750px;}
.menu {
background-color :#FFD700;
float: left;
padding-bottom: 100px;
width:170px;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 12px;
}
.rightside {
background-color: #FFF;
float:left;
width:540;
padding-left:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="subcontent">
<div class="menu">
    <div class="submenu"  style= "background-color:#A80000; text-align:center; width:120px; padding:10px"> 
        <font color= "#FFFFFF"><b>Site Contents</b></font>
    </div>

    <h4><b>Virtual Tour</b></h4>
    <P>Explore the lab to know the insights of the new world!</p>
    <h4><b>Experiments</b></h4>
    <P>There is lot more to it that would fascinate you.</P>
    <h4>Lab History</h4>
    <P> Find out the need to make it underground.</P>
 </div>

 <div class = "rightside">
      <div id="separator" style="background-color: #A80000; height: 20px">
      </div>
          <p id="para1"> Located 2,341 feet beneath the surface in an old iron mine, the lab is deep enough that particle physics experiments see less than 100,00 times the cosmic radiation than on the surface, allowing sensitive searches for exotic particles like neutrinos and dark matter.</P>
     </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes but i want that area with the paragraph that's at the bottom to float right right next to the menu

Comment: OKAY YOU WANT MENUS ON THE LEFT AREA AND CONTENT ON THE RIGHT AREA. AM I RIGHT uSER...?

Comment: I got it why content was not visible because you have an open font tag.